Collection closed under symmetric difference and translation
Basically my question is the following.

Suppose $\mathcal{H}$ is a collection of finite subsets of the natural numbers (containing at least one non-empty set) closed under symmetric difference and translation. Then is it true that it always contain a set of two elements?

One easy observation is the following.
If $\mathcal{H}$ contains a non-trivial arithmetic progression then the claim follows. If $A=\{a, a+d, \ldots, a+nd\}\in \mathcal{H}$, then $\{a, a+(n+1)d\} = A\triangle (A+d)\in \mathcal{H}$
This seems to be a curious question, after spending a few hours, I could not come up with a solution. I have very limited background in these types of questions, so I wanted to know if such questions have been considered in research so far.
Any references that will point me towards a solution are greatly appreciated.
Complete solutions are also most welcome!

Yes. Interpreting 'natural numbers' as $\mathbb{N}_0$, such collections $\mathcal{H}$ correspond to ideals of $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$, by the map sending a set $A$ to the polynomial $\sum_{a \in A} X^a$. Symmetric difference becomes addition of polynomials and translation by $+1$ becomes multiplication by $x$.
Since $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, the image of $\mathcal{H}$ is $\langle f(x) \rangle$ for some $f(x) \in \mathbb{F}_2[x]$. By translation we may assume without loss of generality that $0 \in A$, or equivalently, that $f(0)=1$.
Let $\mathbb{F}_{2^t}$ be a splitting field for $f$. Thus, bearing in mind that there may be repeated roots, there exist $r \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x)$ divides $(x^{2^t-1}+1)^r$. (Since $x^{2^t-1}+1$ has the non-zero elements of $\mathbb{F}_{2^t}$ as its roots.) Equivalently, there exists $q(x) \in \mathbb{F}_2[x]$ such that $q(x)f(x) = (x^{2^t-1} + 1)^r$.
Let $2^s$ be the smallest power of $2$ not less than $r$. Then
$$(x^{2^t-1} + 1)^r (x^{2^t-1} + 1)^{2^s-r} = (x^{2^t-1} + 1)^{2^s} = x^{2^s(2^t-1)} + 1$$
is a weight $2$ polynomial in the ideal generated by $f(x)$. Explicitly, if
$$q(x)(x^{2^t-1} + 1)^{2^s-r} = \sum_{b \in B}x^b$$
then the symmetric difference of all the shifts of $A$ by elements $b \in B$ is a set of size $2$ in $\mathcal{H}$. The final step is a simplification of my original argument, suggested in a comment by Dave Benson.

Isn't it easier to multiply $(x^{2^t-1}+1)^r$ by a further power to reach $(x^{2^t-1}+1)^{2^s}=x^{(2^t-1)2^s} +1$, for $2^s\geqslant r$, which then already has weight two?

It is interesting to note that there exists such families which doesn’t contain singletons, say if we consider the ideal generated by $x+1$

Can we simply say that by the pigeonhole principle there exist two powers of $x$
which are congruent modulo $f(x)$
, thus their difference belongs to the ideal generated by $f$? And we seemingly do not need that every ideal is principal, it suffices that the principal ideal generated by $f$ is contained in our set.

Yes, that's a very nice pigeonhole argument. (My proof is longer I admit, but is constructive.) Again yes, we only used that elements of $\langle f(x) \rangle$ correspond to sets in $\mathcal{H}$.
